# Typescript / protractor . loop through and ElementFinderArray and resolve promises

Tags: typescript, promise, protractor

I want to do the following in protractor (but with typescript):

```
let cellsTxt = await Promise.all(cells.map(cell => cell.getText()));
```

Here I want go through an ElementArrayFinder to get the text of each element.

So far I came up with the following, which is verbose and does not work:

```
let cellsTxt: Array<string> = [];
let cellsTxtPromise: Array<promise.Promise<string>> = [];
cells.forEach((cell: ElementFinder, i:number) => {
  cellsTxtPromise[i] = cell.getText();
})
cellsTxt = await Promise.all(cellsTxt);
```

I welcome any pointer toward the right solution.

thanks!

EDIT: THIS IS NOT A RELEVANT QUESTION; SINCE THE ISSUE I FACED WAS CAUSED BY ANOTHER PIECE OF CODE.

Comment: you can try `let cellsTxt = await cells.getText();`

Comment: thanks a lot yong, actually the mistake came from the function return the ElementArrayFinder. This was an async function so in reality it was returning a promise containing the ElementArrayFinder. I need to play a bit more with it to make sure I understand everything right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks there are several approaches to archive same goal:

```
1) let cellsTxt = await cells.getText(); // you can call getText() on ElementArrayFinder

2) let cellsTxt = await cells.map(cell => await cell.getText()));

3) let cellsTxt = await Promise.all(cells.map(cell => cell.getText()));

4) let tmp = []; 
   let cellsTxt = await cells.each(cell => tmp.push( await cell.getText() ))
                             .then(()=> return tmp;)
```

Comment: but 2 and 3 are a bit complicated with typescript no ? It is going to mutate the variable cells from ElementArrayFinder to an array of strings. It is typescript which is giving me a learning curve here